# Difference between DBMS_METADATA and right click 'view'

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Something strange happened to me today ,my friends(developers) said its probably a bug ... 
Usually when I want to see the DDL of a table in PL/SQL , I right-click on the table and then I click on view and I get the DDL .
However, there is another way I can get the DDL of a table and by right clicking on the table and there something called  DBMS_METADATA then I put my cursor on it and it will show me DDL. In the image that I upload there a difference between the  DBMS_METADATA and the 'view' .Number 1 represents the 'view' and the 2 represents the DBMS_METADATA, if you notice there is a huge difference between the two .The first one shows column organization_code  its not null (because its not checked) but the 2nd one shows organization_code is null. this made the developers confused, which one they should count on ? .But after testing the column its not null. I should mention that is column is a primary key so it should be NOT null why in medata showed a wrongs information ? does that happened to anyone before ?(by the way i am using 11g)

[image: difference info]

Comment: What tool is this?  PL/SQL is not an IDE.  It is a programming language.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Based on the screenshot, it is PL/SQL Developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column used for a primary key cannot be null<sup>1</sup>.  However, that restriction can be enforced solely through a primary key constraint, and does not require a separate not null constraint.  The IDE, PL/SQL Developer, is showing you a generally more useful combination of primary key constraints and not null constraints.  DBMS_METADATA is showing you exactly how the tables were specified, which is irrelevant unless you plan on dropping the primary keys.

```
create table table1(a number not null primary key);
create table table2(a number primary key);

begin
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform,
        'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',false);
end;
/

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TABLE1') from dual;


  CREATE TABLE "JHELLER"."TABLE1" 
  ( "A" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("A") ENABLE
  ) 

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'TABLE2') from dual;


  CREATE TABLE "JHELLER"."TABLE2" 
   (    "A" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("A") ENABLE
   )
```

In PL/SQL Developer, neither column has Nullable checked.

1 Unless you use a novalidated non-unique index, which is extremely rare.